# How to mount a network drive in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: samba, file-sharing

A few days ago I installed Ubuntu 14.04. It has not been possible for me to mount a network drive the same way as it does in Windows. I tried several ways of doing it, but it has not been possible. Previously on Ubuntu 12.04 I had the option to mount a network drive graphically by installing Samba, that way it was listed in Places and then I could mount it by searching for the Shared with Windows option. Now in Ubuntu 14.04 I can't mount a network drive graphically.

I hope you can help me with this.

Comment: As you can see this site is in english and it is required to ask in such language. For support in spanish try http://www.ubuntu-es.org/forum or the #ubuntu-es channel on Freenode IRC server.

Answer (score 1):

To make sure your drives/partitions are mounted properly create a new folder in your `~/media` directory like this:

```
         sudo mkdir /media/windowsshare
```

or

```
         sudo mkdir /media/servername/myshare
```

and input your password when prompted. Next you can visit [Ubuntu Guide for Network Shares](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/MountWindowsSharesPermanently) and follow the instructions present in there.

You can use the `mount` `umount` commands to be able to temporarily mount whatever you want to share until the next reboot when you have to issue the same commands again. To do that follow the next tutorial [listed on this page](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2096864).

Make sure you find out how all your partitions and/or directories to be shared are listed and it would be much easier if you'd decide to install a file manager with full network sharing capabilities like **Dolphin** which is very useful (usually it comes preinstalled in Kubuntu, that is in a KDE environment, but it works on all Ubuntu based distros. No matter the distro version that you are running (Ubuntu, Xubuntu etc) you can install Dolphin as a separate software package with a 'few' extra dependencies :). It will work fine and make your like easier:

```
        sudo apt-get install dolphin
```

or install it via Synaptic Package Manager where you can specifically look for and install all the other dependencies that Dolphin needs to help you share your files.